# Saving data in bigquery simultaneously from a source other than firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

We are trying to log some events based on our application. There are two types of events,

1. Client-side events: logged by an android application using firebase SDK, which is saved to bigquery by firebase
2. Server-side events: we log them using bigquery's go client

Now, firebase stores current day's events into events_intraday_$date table and then flushes that table into partitioned table events_$date.

So, I also logged current day's events into events_intraday_$date table.

> The events got logged successfully into the table but got deleted the next day when the events_intraday_$date table is flushed into events_$date table.

I'm not able to understand how is that happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is [intended behaviour](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en):

> Within each dataset, a table is imported for each day of export. Daily tables have the format "ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD".
>
> Intraday data is imported approximately three times a day. Intraday tables have the format "ga_sessions_intraday_YYYYMMDD". During the same day, each import of intraday data overwrites the previous import in the same table.
>
> When the daily import is complete, the intraday table from the previous day is deleted. For the current day, until the first intraday import, there is no intraday table. If an intraday-table write fails, then the previous day's intraday table is preserved.
>
> Data for the current day is not final until the daily import is complete. You may notice differences between intraday and daily data based on active user sessions that cross the time boundary of last intraday import.