# Server events logged in BigQuery table deleted automatically by Firebase

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to log some events based on our application. There are two types of events:

1. Client-side events: logged by an android application using firebase SDK, which is saved to bigquery by firebase
2. Server-side events: we log them using bigquery's go client

Now, firebase stores current day's events into events_intraday_$date table and then flushes that table into partitioned table events_$date.

So, I also logged current day's server events into events_intraday_$date table but it got deleted by firebase automatically after a while.

The events got logged successfully into the table but got deleted the next day when the events_intraday_$date table is flushed into events_$date table.

Comment: Firebase [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en): "Each row... corresponds to a single event uploaded by the Analytics SDK." Seems that Firebase process intraday tables uploaded by the Analytics SDK only. Open a (support case)[https://firebase.google.com/support/] to confirm this information. I recommend you to load the server events into a different table to [join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#full-outer-join) both tables.

Comment: In addition, seems that this question is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035041).

Comment: Same problem occurs with me. Did you find any answer to this problem?